# Find the centralizer of $(1 2 3)$ in $A_6$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

What is the systematic way of doing this? In lower order groups (significantly less than $6!/2 = 360$ elements!) it's reasonable to find all the elements of the group that when conjugated with $(1 2 3)$ equal $(1 2 3)$. Obviously the cyclic subgroup generated by $(1 2 3)$ is in the centralizer because all powers commute. I also think any permutation of $A_6$ for which $1,2,$ and $3$ are fixed will commute and thus be in the centralizer. Is the centralizer just the union of these two things I've described?

Comment: Let $A_6$ act on itself by conjugation. Check that the orbit containing $(123)$ is the set of all $3$-cycles in $A_6$, of which there are $40$. Thus the stabilizer (centralizer) of $(123)$ has index $40$, hence order $9$. As you noted, any element of $A_6$ that fixes $1,2,3$ will centralize $(123)$, as will the subgroup generated by $(123)$. Is this enough to give you nine elements?

Comment: The hint is not correct -- the size of the centralizer is at least 18 since it contains $(123)$ and a copy of $S_3$ acting on $\{4, 5, 6\}$. The three-cycles in fact split into two conjugacy classes (a fact you can look up) and therefore the size of the centralizer is exactly 18 and so it is this.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**
Let $\tau \in A_6$, belong to the centralizer of $(1 \, 2 \, 3)$ then 
\begin{align*}
\tau (1\,2\,3) \tau^{-1} & = (1\,2\,3)\\
(\tau(1)\,\tau(2)\,\tau(3)) & = (1\,2\,3)
\end{align*}
Of course $\tau$ can be the identity permutation. But we can also have $\tau(1)=2, \tau(2)=3, \tau(3)=1$ and all such cyclical shifts. Now what should $\tau$ do to the set $\{4,5,6\}$? Keeping in mind that $\tau \in A_6$, and we already have that $(1 \, 2 \, 3)$ is an even permutation, therefore  $(\tau(4)\,\tau(5)\,\tau(6))  = (4\,5\,6)$.